# Fastest way to get a single field from all nodes in a local Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I run a Neo4j database locally in which I store personal information. I currently use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) for OS X to search against a field "key" that every node has. Alfred rapidly filters the match list as each character of my query is entered. In order to do this, Alfred needs a list with the "key" field associated with each node in the database. One way to generate this list is with `neo4j-shell`:

```
neo4j-shell -c 'match (n) return n.key;'
```

Unfortunately, this query takes ~1500 ms, which is unacceptably slow for my purposes. Therefore I use a workaround where a cron job periodically dumps the set of keys as a set of empty stub files named by the `key` field. OS X Spotlight indexes these files, and Alfred uses the Spotlight index. This gives excellent search performance, but the list of files being searched against is only as up to date as the last dump. I would like to hit the Neo4j database directly so that I am always searching against the complete list of nodes.

**What is the fastest way to get a single field from all nodes in a local Neo4j database?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting up a simple Ruby API with a single endpoint "keys". The API uses the [neo4j-core](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core) gem to get the list of keys from the database and return it as plaintext. I keep the API running continuously. This is much, much faster than `neo4j-shell`, I guess because of the startup time of the shell.

Answer (score 3):

It's a caching issue, the first time it runs the query it has to load the data from disk.

You would probably want to use DISTINCT: `match (n) return distinct n.key;`

You probably also want to use a label for your nodes.

And a more recent version of Neo4j, like 2.3-M02 should be faster on this too.

Comment: Thanks Michael. A few things: **(1)** I actually do use a label, I just left it out of the query  above to make it more readable. But the first part of my query is really `match (n:mylabel)`. **(2)** the `key` field is already unique on each node, and using `distinct` has no noticeable effect on performance. **(3)** repeated runs of the same query from the command line all take approximately ~1500ms. **(4)** I am using Neo4j 2.2.3. Since you think it's a caching issue but this is not indicated in my tests, is there perhaps a caching setting I can adjust in the configuration?

Comment: @SeanMackesey cache configuration settings you can check here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Thanks for the cache doc reference. Two things: **(1)** I neglected to mention that my initial run of the query after starting the server takes ~3000msec; so the caching cuts the query time in half, but is still too slow. **(2)** I read the caching docs and tried setting the `cache_type` to `strong`, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. If number of possible keys is significantly smaller than a number of all nodes, you can try to keep the keys in separate nodes (with separate label) and connect them to parent nodes with relation. Then get key set from the new node types only.
2. You can create index on key and ask for list of keys only if part of the query was entered by the user (i.e. query has a minimum of 2-3 characters). So if the user has entered "fo", run query

   match (n) where n.key=~'fo.*' return n.key

If he entered on letter only, do nothing, don't run the search.